# Moverme de página cuando selecciono una opción en un select

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Hola buenas tardes quisiera saber como es el código para seleccionar la opción de un select y que cuando seleccione esta opción me mande a otra página.

lo estaba intentando de esta forma y no me da.

```html
<frameset>
<frame id="frameSuperior" src="" /><!-- navegacion -->
<frame id="frameInferior" src="" /><!-- contenidos -->
</frameset> 


   <select name="selectBox" id="selectBox" onchange="cambiarch()">
             <option selected="selected">Archivo</option>
             <option value="<?php echo URL ?>caso/nuevo">Link 1</option>
            
            </select>

            <script type="text/javascript">
             function cambiarch() {
var seleccionado = document.getElementById('selectBox').value;
document.getElementById('frameInferior').src = seleccionado;
}

            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

hola espero ser de ayuda intenta con esto

html

```
  <select name="selectBox" id="selectBox" onchange="cambiarch()">
             <option selected="selected">Archivo</option>
             <option value="google.com">Link 1</option>

  </select>
```

js

```
 function cambiarch() {
      var seleccionado = document.getElementById('selectBox').value;
      alert(seleccionado);
      window.location.replace(seleccionado);
   }
```

faltaria validar que selecionado no sea Archivo o el primer elemento.

saludos :)

Comment: no me funciona amigo

Comment: [enlace]https://codepen.io/DerLeguan/pen/RBEpBJ?editors=1000 ahi tienes el ejemplo la redirecion funciona puedes que tengas un problema en php para setear la ruta, no sale de la ruta obviamente por que codepen no te deja salir a otra ruta por lo que sale un 404.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectBox" id="selectBox">
         <option value="Archivo">Archivo</option>
         <option value="caso/nuevo">Link 1</option>
        
</select>

        <script type="text/javascript">
           
       $("#selectBox").change(function() {
var valor = $(this).val(); 
   
alert("value" + valor);
window.location.href = valor;

});
        </script>
```

Comment: No me funciona amigo, ya estoy usando jquery por medio de carpetas..

Comment: hice una modificacion.. ve si te sirve!